# Column facet: how to align header title to the bottom?

Tags: vega-lite

I would like to align to the bottom all the header titles of my facet columns.

[This is my code](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4Igxg9gdgZglgcxALlANzgUwO4tJKAFzigFcJSBnAdTgBNCALFAZgAY2AacaYsiygAlMiRoVYcAvtxgBDMJnGoQlAA7ySSZAEY2k6SDqzCsvCCiyAtphSHjsgLSYARgCYXAFgCc2gBwBWVw8wLzZfL39-GAB2aK9oumig-1kOEAM5BSVQeEwAGzpbGBBuRkxZOkwAJzM82Wd8gDFeAGU4AC8bZFcuEDqGvIB5KqwiW2cIQkIIS3TuYkI8rpASkEIAT1VlqBmSWTy5lS2wWtl16pQAbVBLWSqAazMNrds7k+4KQmqAJQq4KhQuj03EwUEgdE0ZkgeQgNWUuQKtke3CWCFBhWUCyWtkOlFh2RACIx5kOz22uwsBwMTEUpnhWERyBAaFWlBMYEeyEIVVImHmm2WAEdSLIiHATMQ0DZ9NIbndOaAybYvgAPcQyOB5A5M5x1DmrKp-AE6bT+Ayg8GQ5TQ2FmIlI1ao9FPcXYpm4-F2hnEqCkgW2HaWPZU+aYNVe-LElkyWG3JQlAB02mK-JeTOFooWxjgUtJZRMEcZzNZ7M53N5qaFIrFEpz0v0AF1SiIEGJAb5eth6Ex28CQFVMHi8rnlJQwPsuor83SQCRKlsoJUxvpuAASMdlW62MSEVSUZAAegPUoQsgTCHFjFIzgTcAgB43mFux8wp4ceXFmGP-gTrgTbATAArPFfW4IwTEoRRKDMcDHBcdxnG8PxAmCUJwkiGI4gSJIPBSNJkGuEkdBkWwADloAAAmaAc2VWTkQFI1YWWQFg-x6bRtA8AA2cI2G0LjWO0WUiNcEimXIqAqNhQd1RAeiAFEmJQVw-3YSIPBYdhkkiVxhN9FixIYyjqJkujbBaJSdA8BMWH8MJ2GiLi+N8VxWK4vSUA8QyJKkmjZPo6hLJYbQkw8II4jYDxom0Lxwg8DzkH8QyTNo7h6MY7hmKCBNAn8aJcNcPKCqKhKuOS6TUrk2xFMy5SAO4thokipymoapIEuicq-LMpkLNq7oQo4VxoqGka2GGhLfC60y0tsQL+pYay+LCDxlt8VbdHWhKvEMgBVME6koSg4FyQpZvEyzXC8BMNNiNguKSfxuICRyEt0PaDtkI6TqwM6qqZGrixYv97LiYbXNcAT-CEzhQH0jiPrAQ7jtOnqQD6oH+Ju4bol8FhQiuxz1rNWGiO0UTCVsfaka+lHfrR+agZU-87OiriuI8FyfEayQG30IA)

And I get the below result, the titles are not aligned downwards, each one has a different distance from the graphic bottom.

[image]

How to align these titles to the bottom?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a bug. Can you raise it on GitHub? Here is a workaround.

[image]

```
{
  "data": {"name": "data-eb2eb4918524c908955f7797d7245a00"},
  "facet": {
    "column": {
      "field": "f",
      "header": {"labelOrient": "bottom", "labelFontSize": 20, "title": ""}
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "layer": [
      {
        "mark": {"type": "arc", "outerRadius": 100},
        "encoding": {
          "color": {
            "field": "k",
            "legend": {"title": ""},
            "sort": {"field": "n"},
            "type": "nominal"
          },
          "theta": {"field": "v", "stack": true, "type": "quantitative"}
        }
      },
      {
        "mark": {"type": "text", "fill": "black", "radius": 115},
        "encoding": {
          "color": {
            "field": "k",
            "legend": {"title": ""},
            "sort": {"field": "n"},
            "type": "nominal"
          },
          "text": {"field": "v", "format": ",.1f", "type": "quantitative"},
          "theta": {"field": "v", "stack": true, "type": "quantitative"}
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "resolve": {"scale": {"theta": "independent"}},
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.2.0.json",
  "datasets": {
    "data-eb2eb4918524c908955f7797d7245a00": [
      {"n": 1, "f": "Non Forest", "k": "N", "v": 32.20114689016321},
      {"n": 2, "f": "Non Forest", "k": "E", "v": 22.30554330245552},
      {"n": 3, "f": "Non Forest", "k": "S", "v": 14.350830760182326},
      {"n": 4, "f": "Non Forest", "k": "W", "v": 31.14247904719894},
      {"n": 5, "f": "Forest", "k": "N", "v": 24.525745257452574},
      {"n": 6, "f": "Forest", "k": "E", "v": 20.460704607046072},
      {"n": 7, "f": "Forest", "k": "S", "v": 21.00271002710027},
      {"n": 8, "f": "Forest", "k": "W", "v": 34.010840108401084},
      {"n": 9, "f": "Unclassified", "k": "N", "v": 29.437706725468576},
      {"n": 10, "f": "Unclassified", "k": "E", "v": 32.08379272326351},
      {"n": 11, "f": "Unclassified", "k": "S", "v": 16.427783902976845},
      {"n": 12, "f": "Unclassified", "k": "W", "v": 22.05071664829107}
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have opened a discussion about it two days ago in vega-lite repo https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/discussions/8722#discussion-4863310

Comment: Then the way is to remove the height. Really strange